# Why does this regex does not match

Tags: regex

I'm wondering why the following regex works for some strings and does not work for some others:

```
/^([0-3]+)(?!4|.*5)[0-9]+$/
```

1151 -> this does not match

1141 -> this does match, but why? since I can consider .* as empty and the regex becomes `/^([0-3]+)(?!4|5)[0-9]+$/`

I think that I'm misunderstanding the way the look-ahead works...

Comment: Hold on, what are you trying to accomplish with this expression in plain English? :)

Comment: You want an explanation for your regex? Or do you want to validate something?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Answer (score 9):

Let's look at how the regular expression would parse your string, step by step.

```
^([0-3]+)(?!4|.*5)[0-9]+$
```

First, some clarification. `(?!4|.*5)` is a negative look-ahead that checks if either `4` or `.*5` follow the last consumed character. If it does, the current match fails and steps back. It could also be written as `(?!(4|.*5))` if you wanted it to be slightly more clear about how exactly `|` affects it.

**Let's start by looking at `1141`**

First, `[0-3]+` consumes as many characters as possible, so it will consume up to and including the `11` in `1141`. What's leftover is `41`. The regular expression now checks to see if `4` is after the current characters, and since `?!` is a negative look-ahead, the match will fail if it is found. Since `4` follows `11`, the match fails and the regular expression steps backwards and tries again.

Instead of matching two `1`s, it now attempts a single match and matches `1`, with `141` left over. `?!4` checks to make sure `4` is the next character, and what do you know, it's not there. The regex leaves the negative look-ahead since it didn't match, and continues on to the rest of the regular expression. `141` is matched by the final `[0-9]+`, and thus the entire **`1141` string is matched**. Remember that look-arounds do not consume characters.

**Now let's look at `1151`**

The same thing happens as last time, `11` is consumed and we have `51` left over. Now we look at the negative look-ahead, and evaluate the rest of the string off that. Obviously, `4` is no where in this string so we can ignore that, so let's look at `.*5`.

So the look-ahead `.*5` tries to match `51`. If it does end up matching, just as before the match will fail and the regular expression will step back. Now if you know any regex at all, it is obvious that `.*5` will match the beginning of `51` since `.*` can evaluate to empty.

So we step back, and now we've matched a single `1` instead of both, and we're at the negative look-ahead again.

We have currently consumed `1`, still have `151` left to match, and are on the `(?!4|.*5)` portion of the regex. Here, `4` is obviously non-existant in our string so it is not going to match, so let's look at `.*5` again.

`.*5` will match a portion of `151` since `.*` will consume the first `1`, and the `5` will finish off by matching `5`. This should also be obvious if you know regex.

So we've made a match in a negative look-ahead again, which is bad... so we step back again. We have no more integers to attempt to match with [0-3], and since you can't match 0 integers with a `+`, **the entire string fails to match the regular expression.**

Comment: Indeed, and that explains why the look-around are costly

Answer (score 2):

`1141` matches because the the regular expression engine can backtrack from matching `11` with the `[0-3]+` to just matching the first `1`, leaving the remaining numbers to be matched by the `[0-9]+`.

As the next character after the first `1` is `1` and not `4`, the negative look-ahead, which only looks at the next character, does not prevent the match.

The `1151` does not match because the negative look-ahead with the added `.*` prevents it.

With the added `.*` put before the `5` the look-ahead now means 'don't match if the next character is `4`, or after any number of any characters the next character is `5`' (ignoring newlines).

So even if the engine backtracks to make `[0-3]+` match just the first `1` of `1151`, there is still a `5` ahead in the string, so a match is prevented.

Remember that look-aheads and look-behinds are *zero-width*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to match 4 or 5 the best option would be

```
/^[0-3]+[45][0-9]+$/
```

but without a better explaination of what it's supposed to do it's hard to suggest anything more than that...

Comment: Or even `\d` in stead of `[0-9]`

Comment: I want to know why the regex does not work with the first string but works for the second...

Comment: Why are you trying to use look ahead?

Comment: Well I'm not going to hand-hold you through it then, but this is useful for testing Regex's http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 0):

What regex flavour is that?

/^([0-3]+)**(?!4|.*5)**[0-9]+$/

Honestly the only way I would see it match 1141 and not 1151 is if the highlighted part of the regex would be evaluated as `NOT 4 or .* followed by 5`. If it was that case then the regex engine would fail to find a match for `1141` as it would match the 4 but would miss the 5 to make the inner match complete.

However, usually the alternation would be understood as `4` or `.*5` - which is still not equivalent to 4 or 5, because the expression `.*` can prove quite powerful in case when the engine wants to make a match work.

What are you testing the expression in?